# How to know if static IP is assigned to a company or isp

Tags: static-ip-address

is there a way to know if a static IP is assigned to a ISP? I'm using the [phpwhois](http://www.phpwhois.org/) class to find the IP owner, but I can't find if it is a company or a ISP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<?php 
$domain=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$domain1 = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "Viewer's Server's IP Address: <strong>$domain</strong> - ";
echo "Viewer's PC IP Address: <strong>$domain1</strong>";
?>
```